# Can't train mobilenetssd with custom dataset with tf1 object detection api

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm trying to train a mobilenet ssd using a custom dataset (that has arabic letters in the labels) with tensorflow object detection api and tf 1.15
I converted the data from yolo format to tfrecords using [this repo](https://github.com/mwindowshz/YoloToTfRecords), and the conversion works normally

The training starts and runs for about 800-900 steps then a checkpoint is saved, then loaded to run  evaluation before resuming training, and that's when things go wrong I get this error:

```
  File "/home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 128, in getsize
    return self.font.getsize(text)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u062d' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)


     [[node map_1/while/PyFunc (defined at /home/mai/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
     [[Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/non_max_suppression_with_scores_16/NonMaxSuppressionV5/_2543]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

the letter that causes the error is the first Arabic character encountered in the eval tfrecord file

I'm training using  models/research/object_detection/model_main.py
I think this is an encoding error but I can't find the file where I'd need to fix the encoding since that file keeps on calling more files that doesn't show the actual code in them

Any help fixing the eval issue would be appreciated :D